# Import CSV with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I created a component Joomla and now I want to have the option to import the data for the component. I went through a tutorial but the import feature is not working. Can someone take a look at see if you can help me see why its not working, thanks?

Issue: When I select the csv file and click upload it goes to a blank page and the data is not loaded.

//This is the form feature to upload the file

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="components/com_account_manager/importCSV.php" method="POST">
<p>Choose a file to upload : <input name="file" type="file" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload File" /></p>
</form>
```

//This is the php code for the import

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connec("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());  
    mysql_select_db("test",$conn);

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $handle = fopen($file,"r");

        while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !== false)
        {
            $id = $fileop[0];
            $asset_id = $fileop[1];
            $ordering = $fileop[2];
            $date = $fileop[3];
            $username = $fileop[4];
            $efile_transactions = $fileop[5];
            $state_transactions = $fileop[6];
            $bank_products = $fileop[7];
            $first_overwitholding = $fileop[8];
            $second_overwitholding = $fileop[9];
            $balance_owed = $fileop[10];

            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO account_manager(
            id,
            asset_id,
            odering,
            date,
            username,
            efile_transactions,
            state_transactions,
            bank_products,
            first_overwitholding,
            second_overwitholding,
            balance_owed
            )
            VALUES( 
            '$id',
            '$asset_id',
            '$ordering',
            '$date',
            '$username',
            '$efile_transactions',
            '$state_transactions',
            '$bank_products',
            '$first_overwitholding',
            '$second_overwitholding',
            '$balance_owed')");
        }
        if($sql)
        {
                echo 'CSV file successfully imported.';
            }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your file upload is going **failed** but in that code there is **no validations done for failure**, that's why it is showing blank page
May be your table fields are mismatching

Please chek your table fields.

Comment: Thanks, I did notice I misspelled Ordering on a part of the script, but even after I fixed that and verified the fields I still got the blank page (failed)

Comment: also check your database field, is it same like they appearing in script?